# What is the location of android.databinding.Observable?

Tags: android, android-sourcesets

Android Studio 3.0.1 is complaining that it can't find this class. Even though it builds, it just shows an awful red underline. That's my first question, but also curious where IS this elusive class?

Looking in the expanded libraries it doesn't show it: /Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/databinding/library/1.3.1/library-1.3.1-sources.jar

And looking online for the source I'm also coming up short:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/data-binding/+/c9a5d6f140f732ca0ff279a4b1ee315072e1c422/library/src/main/java/android/databinding

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/data-binding/+/master/baseLibrary/src/main/java/android/databinding/Observable.java derived stuff is here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/data-binding/+/master/extensions/library/src/main/java/android/databinding

Comment: @TimCastelijns nice google-foo! Not sure why it didn't come up for me

Comment: I didn't google it. Just searched the repo by hand, in places where I expected it to show up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Android Studio 3.0.1 is complaining that it can't find this class. Even though it builds, it just shows an awful red underline

That's odd. I just pulled up a project in AS 3.0.1 that uses the data binding framework, and I can import `android.databinding.Observable` just fine.

Then again, Android Studio is... quirky.

> where IS this elusive class?

In my environment, it is in `com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:3.0.1`:

[image: Android Studio 3.0.1, Showing Data Binding Dependency]

That, and `com.android.databinding:adapters:1.3.1` and `com.android.databinding:library:1.3.1`, are added to your dependencies by the Android Gradle Plugin if you enable data binding.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the gradle plugin version, synced, and then reverted and synced and now I see the baseLibrary jar.

Answer (score 1):

The link you provided refers to commit SHA `c9a5d6f` which is from some time ago:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/data-binding
cd data-binding
git show c9a5d6f

commit c9a5d6f140f732ca0ff279a4b1ee315072e1c422
Author: George Mount <mount@google.com>
Date:   Fri Jul 10 15:43:11 2015 -0700
```

Looking at the "current" (as of Nov 27, 2017), it is present:

```
ls baseLibrary/src/main/java/android/databinding/Observable.java
```